# Kotlin: Cannot import-on-demand from object

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to make a library where you can call functions of an `object` through "static imports" (import-on-demand in Kotlin). Unfortunately Kotlin seems to have a limitation as seen below.

[image]

Why is this a limitation? Is there anything I can do to get around it? (I've tried using a class with a companion object and in that case the functions don't even resolve.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although you cannot `import package.KotlinObject.*` from a Kotlin object directly, you *can* `import package.*`. To avoid unnecessary or ambiguous imports, simply create a new package, declare the classes, variables or extensions you wish to import inside a raw `.kt` file and then import-on-demand from the parent package.

Comment: This imo is the more useful answer

Comment: @ElSushiboi Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 15):

Sparkot is your Kotlin class, if I understand it's right.
Objects may inherit things from supertypes, e.g. `equals()`, `hashCode()` will be imported every time you<sup>*</sup> import from an object, and the decision was made that this would be too confusing.

<sup>*</sup> - imports work only with Java object.

Comment: `Sparkot` is a Kotlin object, a singleton class.

Comment: Well, Kotlin supports importing only individual members of objects by name, not a *-import. The IDE helps with it.

Comment: It's helpful to at least hear the thinking behind this decision, but this limitation is the reason I've now decided to unconvert a Kotlin conversion back to Java. Kotlin is presented as a language that would help in creating a language plugin for IntelliJ — and it does — but this is one place where it certainly doesn't. Just about anyone who uses an IElementType-holder class WILL want to import all of its symbols in places that heavily use it and for which there are no conflicts (if they value living without carpal tunnel pain, that is). ...

Comment: Instead of helping this particular scenario, IIRC I think I might have even seen a JetBrains-developed plugin flat-out descend from/sub-class their IElementType-holder class just to get around that. Such a workaround is certainly not efficient, and definitely a worse situation than the one that this rationale was trying to avoid. I'm not saying I don't get the thinking behind the limitation... just discussing how it may hurt more than help.

Comment: "descend from/sub-class their IElementType-holder class whenever they needed to use it"*